# Configure total request timeout for a httpclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, apache-commons-httpclient, resilience4j

I am using `RestTemplate` in Spring Boot, and here we have 3 timeout configs we can set on it.

- `connectTimeout` : max time to acquire connection.
- `readTimeout/socketTimeout` : max time between two data packets to arrive,
- `connectionRequestTimeout`: max time during which a connection must be obtained from the pool. (If pool is being used)

Downstream service has a `p99.9` around `200ms`, hence I want to set the total timeout for the operation of a request/response cycle for a request to be 200ms at max.

It seems that there's no way of doing this on `RestTemplate`. If I set `readTimeout/socketTimeout = 200ms`, it can happen all data packets arrived under 200ms, but still the total req/response cycle took 400ms, if this happens I want to timeout the entire request as soon as it exceeds 200ms.

I feel as a owner of the upstream service I do care more about the entire req/response cycle time after connection is established instead of socketTimeout/readTimeout.

**Is that possible with `RestTemplate` OR should we use some other library to restrict the total timeout of entire req/response cycle?**

Comment: Sidenote: `RestTemplate` is deprecated on latest springboot versions so for the alternastive called `WebClient` you can simply call a setting function `responseTimeout()` on creating the client. It takes a duration and you can also configure a default at the application properties file.

Comment: responseTimeout will be the total req/response cycle timeout when using WebClient? @LenglBoy

Comment: That's the time when the WebClient will make the current call fail. So App A is calling App B using WebClient. Since it is a synchronous call A will wait for the answer of B OR fail if there is no response more early.

Comment: Understood, so it timeouts if we don't get the complete response under that time, instead of data packets of the response. @LenglBoy